# Dynamically add views and handle their events

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I hope this is any easy one. I have a view that I want to add and remove view (buttons, imagebuttons, etc) dynamically. I also want to respond to the events triggered by these views across all my activities. So, in other words I have a basic view, that I need to add and remove buttons as necessary. When these buttons are there I need to have the ability to respond to clicks, etc.

Essentially this is a menu bar with buttons. The view will be merged into the views of each activity.

Is this something that is done with a BaseActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a reference to the parent layout and then use `addView()` on the parent to dynamically add a `Button` or whatever.

With `addView()` you can set the new layout parameters for the button so as to control it's position. Defining the OnClickListener's for each of the button's is possible as well.
Let me know if you need more specific advice.

Comment: So I would need to do this on each activity? I get what you are suggesting but I am not clear on implementation. I have 4 activities that would need to control which buttons are in this view and to handle the events (click). This view is merged into each specific activities view. Each activity I have has it's own layout and withing each layout is this toolbar(x) layout that was merged into each activities layout. I needed each activity to have the ability to dynamically add view to layout x. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: I think I understand. Is what your thinking of something like a Tab Layout that you can dynamically add tabs to? 

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) and tell me what you think

Comment: Or is it unrelated to the activities themselves and you just want a consistent dynamic toolbar? ('consistent dynamic' is not an oxymoron I promise :))
In that case maybe subclass a layout that is held in the Application context (by subclassing Application) and make changes to that, and when you switch to another activity inflate from that statically held view.